# C# How to call KeyUp event in button?

Tags: c#, events, button, datagridview, keyup

I have this code that I can only execute via KeyPress and I want to call the event via button so that it will run as if I am pressing the actual key on thw keyboard. Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) { 
        dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(this.dataGridView1, _
                                      new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, _
                                                                    this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index));
    } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) {
        dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(this.dataGridView1, _
                                      new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, _
                                                                    this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Button present in the Datagrid??

Answer (score 2):

Why not just call the event on the button's **click handler**

```
void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1_KeyUp(dataGridView1,new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Down));
}
```

This is true for any function call or a handler call.